# prove $|1-z\bar{w}|^2-|z-w|^2=0$ complex numbers

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, complex-numbers

how would you prove that for $z,w \in \Bbb{C}$ if $|z|=1$ then 
$|1-z\overline w|^2-|z-w|^2=0$? I let $z=x+iy$ and $w=a+ib$ and after doing the required modulus operations and simplifications i was left with
$(xa+yb)^2-a^2-b^2$ but from here im stuck on how to show that it equals zero. Thanks

Comment: You mean $|1-z\overline w|^2-|z-w|^2=0$ surely?

Comment: sorry my mistake edited now

Answer (score 2):

Note that $|z-w|=|z||1-z^{-1}w|=|1-\overline zw|$. Is that the same
as $|1-z\overline w|$?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother writing $z = x+iy$. Rather use the simple formula $$|a-b|^2 = |a|^2 - 2\renewcommand{\Re}{\mathop{\mathrm{Re}}} \Re \bar a  b + |b|^2.$$

Spoiler follows.

> Observe $$|1 - z \bar w|^2 = 1 - 2 \Re {z \bar w} + |z \bar w|^2 = |z|^2 - 2 \Re \bar z  w + |w|^2 = |z-w|^2$$

Comment: How did you get this "simple formula" ,are there $a$ and $b$ complex numbers?

Answer (score 1):

[I write $N(x)$ for $x\bar x $ because I don't know how to type "modulus"].

For any complex $z$, $N(z)=1$ iff $\bar z = z^{-1}$, so $N(1-z\bar w)=N(1-z^{-1}\ w)$ (on taking conjugates inside) $=N(z^{-1}z-z^{-1}w)=N(z^{-1})N(z-w)= N(z-w)$.